# Pandas to_csv makes timestamps into tuples

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, pandas

I have a dataframe with a column of timestamps that I'd like to write to a `CSV` file, but running into some problems as it seems to be outputting a tuple.

```
print df['mydate'].loc[0], type(df['mydate'].loc[0])
```

yields

```
2009-01-01 00:00:00 <class 'pandas.tslib.Timestamp'>
```

When I use `df.to_csv()`, the `timestamps` are written as a tuple and thus not recognized by Excel as a date.

What it looks like in the csv file:

```
(Timestamp('2015-02-25 00:00:00'),)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to get a date that is recognised by Excel, try doing `df['mydate'] = df.mydate.dt.date.astype(str)` before saving it as a csv.

If you wanted the time too, you can leave out the `.dt.date` part. For completeness, you can use [`.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) to get things according to some custom format, although this is probably not necessary in this particular case.