# Parse Timestamp tuple into date while reading csv file with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, python-xarray

I have a number of CSV files I need to parse into Pandas dataframes with time as index. I automatically parse the date in the file [using](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) `df = pd.read_csv("infile.csv",parse_dates=["index"],dayfirst=False)`. For some of my files this fails as a proper date format is not found but rather a Timestamp tuple that looks like this:

```
    ,index,tos,model_member,member_id,model,experiment_id
0,"(0, Timestamp('1950-01-31 00:00:00'), 0)",4.740208145290402,KACE-1-0-G-r1i1p1f1_ssp245,r1i1p1f1_ssp245,KACE-1-0-G,ssp245
1,"(0, Timestamp('1950-01-31 00:00:00'), 1)",4.740208145290402,KACE-1-0-G-r1i1p1f1_ssp245,r1i1p1f1_ssp245,KACE-1-0-G,ssp245
2,"(0, Timestamp('1950-01-31 00:00:00'), 2)",4.740208145290402,KACE-1-0-G-r1i1p1f1_ssp245,r1i1p1f1_ssp245,KACE-1-0-G,ssp245
3,"(0, Timestamp('1950-01-31 00:00:00'), 3)",4.740208145290402,KACE-1-0-G-r1i1p1f1_ssp245,r1i1p1f1_ssp245,KACE-1-0-G,ssp245
```

I have looked high and low for a nice way to convert this into a date during reading of the file, but I can not find one. Any suggestions would be helpful. The timestamp comes from extracting data from NetCDF files and then writing the data to CSV using the Python library `xarray` and the function `[xarray.Dataset.to_netcdf][2]`. I would also be very interested if there is a way to avoid writing Timestamp to file in the first place, but rather a string date e.g. `%Y-%m-%h`. I see questions close to mine but [their solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40937538/pandas-to-csv-makes-timestamps-into-tuples) did not work for me. My current way of writing data to file is, which I thought would work:

```
 df.to_csv("filename.csv", date_format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could read the csv without any automatic date parsing and then [**`extract`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) the date manually by capturing `r"'(.*)'"`:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('infile.csv', index_col=0)
df['index'] = df['index'].str.extract(r"'(.*)'")
df['index'] = pd.to_datetime(df['index'])
```

|  | index | tos | model_member | member_id | model | experiment_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1950-01-31 | 4.740208 | KACE-1-0-G-r1i1p1f1_ssp245 | r1i1p1f1_ssp245 | KACE-1-0-G | ssp245 |
| 1 | 1950-01-31 | 4.740208 | KACE-1-0-G-r1i1p1f1_ssp245 | r1i1p1f1_ssp245 | KACE-1-0-G | ssp245 |
| 2 | 1950-01-31 | 4.740208 | KACE-1-0-G-r1i1p1f1_ssp245 | r1i1p1f1_ssp245 | KACE-1-0-G | ssp245 |
| 3 | 1950-01-31 | 4.740208 | KACE-1-0-G-r1i1p1f1_ssp245 | r1i1p1f1_ssp245 | KACE-1-0-G | ssp245 |

Comment: Brilliant! Your solution worked like a charm. I will definitely use the `extract` method more in the future.